# O que significa na prática o urlencoded do Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Analisando um código construído sobre a plataforma Nodejs, acabei me deparando com a instrução `express.urlencoded({ extended: false })`, para tentar compreender a mesma, acabei recorrendo à documentação do Expressjs, entretanto não consegui compreender o que está significa, faz e qual sua importância no código.

Ficarei grato caso alguém possa responder as dúvidas levantadas no texto acima. Bem como comentar a relevância do { extended: false }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa noite.
A opção "extended" diz para o express qual biblioteca ele deve utilizar para fazer o parsing do conteúdo das requisições que ele recebe.
Quando extended : true vai utilizar a biblioteca [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) e quando for false ele vai utilizar a biblioteca [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

A diferença entre elas é que a biblioteca qs permite o aninhamento de objetos (nested objects), que é praticamente como o JSON trabalha:

```
// {"animal":{"tipo":"cachorro","raca":"vira-lata","idade":3}}
```

E a biblioteca querystring não suporta nested objects.

Fonte: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: Compreendi, e qual o significado de `express.urlencoded`? É um middleware para lidar com parâmetros na URL?

Comment: na verdade o middleware é o body-parser, você instala ele como modulo do express para dar a habilidade ao express de analisar o conteúdo das solicitações antes de fazermos alguma manipulação. (em poucas palavras ele deixa o conteúdo do body das requisições tudo bonitinho pra gente trabalhar mais fácil esses dados)
e o urlencoded é um método desse middleware que pode receber parâmetros, como o extended que falamos, outros parâmetros que ele aceita vc encontra ali no link que deixei.

Comment: @MuriloPortugal você explicou bastante sobre o parâmetro `extended` mas o que exatamente faz o `urlencoded` ? Eu sei que o `express.json()` é um parser das informações vindas de uma requisção post mas e o `urlencoded` ? Ele seria para fazer um parser de parâmetros passados na URL como por exemplo "http://site.com/name=lucas" ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 o `urlencoded` é um parser das informações vindas no body da request. Veja na [documentação](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#express.urlencoded)