# Erro na criação de api rest em Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

O erro que esta retornando é `C:\Users\Eric Vitta\Documents\documentos cursos\javascript\src>node index.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at router.post (C:\Users\Eric Vitta\Documents\documentos cursos\javascript\src\app\controller\projectController.js:37:31) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Eu estou criando uma API para fazer testes no Jmeter, Estou usando o insomnia para fazer os testes e passar informações para o cadastro.

Esse é o link do github com todo o código https://github.com/ericvitta/apiteste

É uma API para testar os métodos REST, somente com intuito de estudo e aprimoramento nas linguagem.
Eu não sei o porque não esta retornando valores no comando req.body pois passo as informações no formato JSON.
[image: Erro que aparece quando testo no Insomnia]

```js
const mongoose = require('../../database');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    require: true,
  },
  tasks: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Task',
  }],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);

module.exports = Project;

const mongoose = require('../../database');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  project: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project',
    require: true,
  },
  assignedTo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    require: true,
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    require: true,
    default: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);

module.exports = Task;
```

```js
const express = require ('express');
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/auth');

const Project = require('../models/Project');
const Task = require('../models/Task');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(authMiddleware);

router.get('/', async (_req, res) => {
   try {
       const projects = await Project.find().populate(['user', 'tasks']);
       return res.send({ projects});

   }catch (err) {
       return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao carregar projetos.'});
   }
});

router.get('/:projectId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const project = await Project.findById(req.params.projectId).populate(['user', 'tasks']);
        return res.send({ project});
 
    }catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao carregar projetos.'});
    }
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { title, description, tasks } = req.body;

        const project = await Project.create({ title, description, user: req.userId });
      
      await Promise.all(tasks.map(async task => {

          const projectTask = new Task({...task, project: project._id}); 

          await projectTask.save();

         project.tasks.push(projectTask);
    }));
        
        await project.save();  

      return res.send({ project });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao criar novo projeto.' });
    }
});

router.put('/:projectId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { title, description, tasks } = req.body;

        const project = await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.projectId , {
            title,
            description
        }, {new: true});

        project.tasks = [];
        
        await Task.remove({ project: project._id});
      
      await Promise.all(tasks.map(async task => {

          const projectTask = new Task({...task, project: project._id}); 

          await projectTask.save();

         project.tasks.push(projectTask);
         console.log({ tasks });
    }));
        
        await project.save();  

      return res.send({ project });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao criar novo projeto.' });
    }
});

router.delete('/:projectId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Project.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.projectId);
        return res.send({ Message:'Projeto removido com sucesso.'});
 
    }catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Erro ao deletar projeto.'});
    }
});



module.exports = app => app.use('/projects', router);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, altere no INSONIA a sua requisição http a chave "tarefas" para "tasks" como esta no seu código. (como mencionado pelo amigo Christian Luã Lemos)

```
 const { title, description, tasks } = req.body;
```

Fora isso, reparei que você utiliza no seguinte código:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

Altere para:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

Isso porque com a opção true vai fazer o body-parser utilizar a biblioteca [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs), esta biblioteca consegue trabalhar com nested objects.
Falei sobre ela nesse outro link: [O que significa na prática o urlencoded do Expressjs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402275/o-que-significa-na-pr%c3%a1tica-o-urlencoded-do-expressjs/402280#402280)

Comment: Fiz as alterações mas o erro ainda acontece

Comment: O erro `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` é claro, ele não encontra o método map porque a variável que esta tentando utiliza-lo é undefined. Copiei seu projeto do github e funciona, somente acerte os nomes conforme seu código. Se você diz ao programa 'const { title, description, tasks } = req.body;' ele espera que no corpo da requisição tenha as tags title, description e tasks. Revise sua requisição no insónia novamente e compare se os nomes estão exatamente iguais ao do seu código. Este erro que você informou na pergunta é exatamente isso. Confirme se não esta dando outro erro agora.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção, eu baixei o projeto na maquina de um amigo e funcionou...

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! uma dica, não se esqueça de marcar o extended como true como disse ali na minha resposta, isso vai fazer com que você possa trabalhar com objetos aninhados, o que é importante como você esta trabalhando com JSON, caso contrário se você responder com um JSON que tenha aninhamento ele não vai sair. Se a resposta te ajudou de alguma maneira, marque como certa para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Você está pegando os atributos `title`, `description` e `tasks` do objeto `req.body` neste linha:

```
const { title, description, tasks } = req.body;
```

O erro que está ocontecendo no projeto está indicando que a variável `tasks` é `undefined`, isto é, não existe `req.body.tasks`.

Este efeito pode ser observado no código abaixo:

```js
let obj = {title : "foo", description : "bar"}
let {title, description, tasks} = obj

console.log(title) //foo
console.log(description) //bar
console.log(tasks) //undefined
```

Comment: EU imaginei isso mas na parte de criação da Schema do mongo eu coloquei tasks e ja conferi o nome várias vezes mas não consegui entender o porque não esta trazendo os dados

Comment: Confere se a sua requisição HTTP possui o parâmetro tasks.

Comment: Verifiquei e na imagem eu tinha trocado o nome do parâmetro para tarefa para ver se era algum conflito com o nome  mas o erro continua igual, tentei colocar  um console.log para retornar o valor mas não retorna nada

Comment: Eu ia tentar usar um cliente http como o Postman (https://www.getpostman.com), criando manualmente uma requisição POST com os parâmetros title, description e tasks.

Comment: Esse insomnia que estou usando faz o mesmo processo, você cria sua requisição , no formato que precisar e passar o localhost + porta que definiu no código e você faz esse processo de testar, eu fiz um outro cadastro para usuario e funcionou , gravou no banco mongo e tudo mas essa parte do projeto e das tasks esta com esse problema